# Regexp how do a match a not equal

Tags: regex

Data

```
Bla bla usr/bin/rcp bla bla
Bla bla usr/bin/awl bla bla
Bla bla usr/bin/cp bla bla
Bla bla usr/bin/ftp bla bla
Bla bla usr/bin/cut bla bla
```

Ignore list

```
cp
ftp 
rcp
```

**Problem** 
I Need a regular expression (Java ish) that will process the data lines (of which there will be many others) and if usr/bin/ is found show it as a match but only if not followed by a word on the ignore list

Comment: how do you want to handle `usr/bin/cpp` ?

Comment: Hi @David Kirch, welcome to stackoverflow! You should post your regexp attempt, or explain where you got stuck, so others can help you.. If you show effort, others will be motivated to help!

Comment: cpp is not cp and so is not ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please see Regex Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/nR4nR4/1)

```
usr\/bin\/(?!cp|ftp|rcp)
```

Comment: You could also write this `usr\/bin\/(?!(c|ft|rc)p)` if you were inclined to save exactly one keystroke :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a negative lookahead regex here, try this regex:

```
user/bin/(?!(cp|ftp|rcp))
```